# VBA in MS Access lookup value in Temp Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a sales configuration database.  I am using forms to step salesman through the configuration process.  Certain products will determine the path of configuration.  As the salesmen click through the forms, I have a temporary table (tblConfigTemp) being populated with their choices.  This table gets cleared at the end of the configuration or anytime the user presses the 'home' button.

I am having issues with VBA on how to lookup values on my temporary table.  I want to be able to look at my temporary table, search for a ProductID and then insert an additional ProductID based on previous entries.  Here is what have so far:

```
Private Sub btnRTKGO_Click()

    Dim locProductID As Integer

    locProductID = [Tables]![ConfigTemp]![ProductID]

    If locProductID = 1 Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO ConfigTemp( [ProductID] ) SELECT  '10' "
    ElseIf locProductID = 2 Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO ConfigTemp( [ProductID] ) SELECT  '11' "
    ElseIf locProductID = 3 Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO ConfigTemp( [ProductID] ) SELECT  '12' "
    ElseIf locProductID = 4 Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO ConfigTemp( [ProductID] ) SELECT  '13' "
    Else
        Call MsgBox("This is a pop-up message", 0, "A Message")
    End If

End Sub
```

Been awhile since I have done any programming, trying to get back into the saddle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a little detail regarding the actual problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

The *Domain functions* `DLookUp()`, `DCount()`, etc. are often the most straightforward ways of doing simple lookups in Access. For example, to see if [ProductID] number 1 exists you could do something like

```
Dim n As Integer
n = DCount("*", "ConfigTemp", "ProductID=1")
If n = 0 Then
    MsgBox "ProductID number 1 was not found."
Else
    MsgBox "ProductID number 1 was found."
End If
```

For additional information see the Microsoft KB article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786).

To add another row to the table, you could either use something similar to the syntax in your sample code...

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
cdb.Execute "INSERT INTO ConfigTemp (ProductID) VALUES (10)", dbFailOnError
```

...or you could use a Recordset object

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("ConfigTemp", dbOpenTable)
rst.AddNew
rst!ProductID = 10
rst.Update
rst.Close
```